# Pyinstaller ModuleNotFound Error: 'urllib3.packages.six.moves'

Tags: python, windows-services, pyinstaller

I'm trying to package a script using pyinstaller to run as a windows service. When trying to run it I get the `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib3.packages.six.moves'` error. I'm using the command

`pyinstaller.exe --onefile --runtime-tmpdir=. --hidden-import win32timezone --hidden-import urllib3 laps_service.py`

in a virtual environment. You'll see there that I added it as a `--hidden-import` but that didn't make any difference.

After some googling I found that uninstalling and reinstalling urllib3 and requests could help, so I've done that - I explicitly installed `requests==2.24.0` because `servicemanager` required 2.24.0; when this installed, pip automatically uninstalled `urllib3-2.1.0` and installed the compatible version `urllib3-1.25.11`, but I'm still getting the same error. (Edit: I also installed six)

From memory this script worked absolutely fine as a pyinstaller exe in a venv previously (on a laptop I no longer have), so I don't think there's any problem with the code and instead probably something with the versions of some package. I've run `pip check` but it found no broken dependencies.

Full Traceback is below and I can give a list of imported packages if that's helpful.

(Edit: I also have a working (but older and slightly different version) of the compiled .exe so if there's a way of getting into that to see the versions, that might help)

```
PS C:\LAPS> .\laps_service.exe --startup delayed install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "laps_service.py", line 29, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "requests\__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "urllib3\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "urllib3\exceptions.py", line 2, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib3.packages.six.moves'
[14276] Failed to execute script 'laps_service' due to unhandled exception!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end this was some kind of dependency conflict - I uninstalled `urllib3` and `requests`, and then reinstalled `requests` - this triggered a reinstall of some `urllib3` stuff. I don't quite know why, so here's the traceback for posterity:

```
pip install requests
Collecting requests
  Using cached requests-2.31.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.6 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<4,>=2 in c:\nosync\projects\laps\.venv\lib\site-packages (from requests) (3.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in c:\nosync\projects\laps\.venv\lib\site-packages (from requests) (2.10)
Collecting urllib3<3,>=1.21.1 (from requests)
  Using cached urllib3-2.1.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.4 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\nosync\projects\laps\.venv\lib\site-packages (from requests) (2023.11.17)
Using cached requests-2.31.0-py3-none-any.whl (62 kB)
Using cached urllib3-2.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (104 kB)
Installing collected packages: urllib3, requests
Successfully installed requests-2.31.0 urllib3-2.1.0
```

I then tested it before freezing with pyinstaller, and it couldn't find a module of `servicemanager` - turns out I had also installed a stand-alone `servicemanager` when I didn't need to because it's included with `pywin32`, and there was a conflict there. So I uninstalled `servicemanager`.

At some point in all this it fixed itself, so my advice would be to either start fresh or systematically uninstall everything and reinstall one by one, running the script for errors. Not a completely satisfying answer, but an answer nonetheless.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Try install the package six

```
pip install six
```

https://github.com/benjaminp/six

Comment: Yes I installed six after seeing the error. Sorry forgot to mention that, will add it to the question

Comment: Have you added six to the hidden import

Comment: just tried that; still the same error

Comment: Iv had this happen to me before, what i did was create a new virtual environment and still deps from scratch (this is a bit of a last resort action as it could fix hidden conflicts)

Comment: Another solution may be to either downgrade deps or if applicable use a different bundling tool like py2exe or cx_freeze